# How to prevent table from expanding dynamically in css?

Tags: jquery, css, easyautocomplete

```
  <table>
          <tr>
            <td> <label>Search name </label></td>
            <td> <input type="text" id="searchName" > </td>
         </tr>

        <tr>....</tr>
        <tr>....</tr>
        <tr>....</tr>
   </table>
```

So I have table structure like this.When I search name in input box using easyautocomplete plugin,the dropdown list comes which increased the height of

```
<td> <input type="text" id="searchName" > </td>
```

and so label of this particular tr and other tr are shifted down. I don't want the the table to shift dynamically

Comment: Add vertical align top to td or style the input so it uses less height or is absolutely positioned?

Comment: I added vertical-align:top to the top tr so now label is not shifting down.But  other tr are still moving down

Comment: try the absolute positioning for the input then - that way it will take no space and won't cause the thing to shift down - it's hard to know what's causing the shift without a [MCVE]

Comment: absolute positioning should work indeed - but we'd need to see the exact code you have. Please host your example on a web project sharing tool like https://codepen.io or https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: yeah I got it worked using absolute positioning